# What level do I have to be to kill Hinterlands/Storm coast dragon?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

The Hinterlands dragon is level 12 and whenever I go in there it murders me.
What level do I need to be to have a smidge of a chance?

In the Sword coast I "helped" the dragon by killing the giant. now I cant find the dragon. Where is it and can I kill it with a level 11 party?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do it at level 11 - but it's really tough. You'll need a good composition, armor with high resistances and lots of potions to help you. I did it at level 16 without much preparation and it was a breeze (on normal). Just make sure to dodge the fire blasts from the sky - those can *really* hurt, especially at level 11!

The Storm Coasts dragon flies off to a place which cannot be reached until much later in the game, after doing a quest. **Mouse-over the block below to find out more (warning: SPOILER ALERT)**.

> The sidequest is called Red Water, which opens up Dragon Island in the Storm Coasts.

Once you can reach it, I think it's level 19, so no - no chance of doing that with a level 11 party.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you only need to be level 1, it will however take forever. There is a massive boulder at the entrance to the area where the dragon is in. I solo'd it with my mage by simply shooting it over and over until it threw a fireball in my direction, hid behind the boulder and then returned to shooting it.

Killed the dragon at level 10ish. Your party members will either go in, shoot a few times and then teleport back to you, or get brutally mauled, but it should be fairly easy to pull off if you simply use your mage.

Answer (score 0):

Go behind the hinterlands dragon and you will see a stack of wood and a basket with rocks in it stand behind that and shoot him if he gets to far away run up a bit he will fly to you then run back to the basket

Answer (score 0):

I've had things bug out and simply not attack too, but it only happens occasionally. It is possible to kill the Hinterlands dragon at level 3. Just turn off AI and use a mage to shoot him as soon as you see him, before he flies off.

Even on the easiest difficulty, it will take a while though. Using a crafted frost staff and frost spells makes it go faster. Obviously that's a fairly cheap way of doing it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

At level 10, I loaded up with potions and regeneration flasks: if you're not a mage - make sure you take two mages instead of one.  I took Cassandra as my tank, and set the AI so that everyone's preferred tactics were Guard/ Barrier/ Cold /WarCry/LifeWard abilities and spells.  I then took over Cassandra while my main rouge just went crazy with poisoned arrows.

Both mages went berserk with cold spells and barriers - and I put Cassandra to work on the dragon's hind legs.  We didn't retreat, and for the most part until the dragonlings were in my face, I ignored them.

It took a while, but they bought down the dragon with only 1 death (who actually revived before the end).

Last note: if either of your mage takes and damage early, before they fall under the regen potion threshold, have them quaff a regeneration potion.  Save the full heal potions until clutch time if you can.